# how can I select one column multiple time with different condition?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to make a selection from 2 different tables, that results in a output like this:

```
Punchdate | EmployeeCode | Name | Punch_in | Break | Lunch | Second_start | Break | Punch out
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11.08.2005      1021    John Smith   7:00    9:00     12:00    1:00         3:10      4:30
```

**dbo.Punchintervals**

```
employee(dbo.punchintervals.employee=dbo.employee.objid)
intime
outime
department/*(dbo.punchintervals.department = dbo.emprole.objid*/
/*(intime column has all the punches form all the departments,they need to be sorted trough the department column)*/
```

**dbo.employee**

```
employee/*(dbo.employee.objid=dbo.punchinterval.employee)*/
name
code
```

**dbo.emprole**

```
objid/*objid is just a vule example 10 (dbo.emprole.objid = dbo.punchinterval.department)*/
name/*(name of the role example: quality control, punch out, lunch,break)*/
```

so far this was my last attemp

```
SELECT     TOP (100)
  PUNCHDATE,CODE,name 
        ,( 
            SELECT  [sitewatch].[dbo].Punchinterval.INTIME
            FROM    [sitewatch].[dbo].Punchinterval AS PunchIn 
            WHERE   [sitewatch].[dbo].Punchinterval.DEPARTMENT = '10' 

        ) AS Startime 
        ,( 
             SELECT  [sitewatch].[dbo].Punchinterval.INTIME
            FROM    [sitewatch].[dbo].Punchinterval AS PunchIn 
            WHERE   [sitewatch].[dbo].Punchinterval.DEPARTMENT = '11' 
        ) AS break2 

FROM    [sitewatch].[dbo].Punchinterval,[sitewatch].[dbo].employee
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.employee
JOIN dbo.Punchintervals ON dbo.punchintervals.employee=dbo.employee.objid
JOIN dbo.emprole ON dbo.emprole.objid = dbo.punchinterval.department
```

Comment: The join is a great idea but we need the condition to retrieve the proper start time where department = 10,11,12 or dbo.employeerole.name = 'quality control','production','sales','management'

Comment: You can add those criteria to your where clause ;-)